# Power BI measure to return date 'n' days from today

Tags: powerbi

I have a table with the columns below.

[image: Product Id, No of days Stock Available]

I need to add a measure to calculate the Stock Run Out Date. For example, Product Id '1' will run out in 5 days and the value should be 2023-09-25 assuming today is 20th of September.

I used DATEADD, and various things but couldn't get it to work. Can anyone suggest how this can be achieved?

Comment: I found a way to do this. The measure below is working.

DATE(YEAR(TODAY()),MONTH(TODAY()),DAY(TODAY())+[Days Cover])

I am pretty sure there should be a better method to do it

Comment: DATEADD: The explanation is same as with another similar question posted these days. Dax time intelligence has some requirements regarding your data model. https://dax.guide/dateadd/ Good luck!